# Two ternary operator’s in one line causing a "Failed to compile" error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am guessing this is a small syntax error but I cannot seem to find a clear cut answer as to where the syntax error is. I am trying to run two if else statements in one line for 'style'

My code is below

```
 <div
              class="secondColorPicker"
              style={{
                displaySecondColorPicker ? showColorPicker : hideColorPicker
              }, 
              {
                activeColorPicker == 'second' ? hideColorPicker : showColorPicker
              }}
            >
              <ChromePicker
                color={secondColorInput}
                onChange={handleSecondColorPicker}
              />
            </div>
```

The syntax in itself is

```
{{
                displaySecondColorPicker ? showColorPicker : hideColorPicker
              }, 
              {
                activeColorPicker == 'second' ? hideColorPicker : showColorPicker
              }}
```

The two classes in question

```
 const showColorPicker = {
    display: "block",
  }

  const hideColorPicker = {
    display: "none",
  }
```

The two states in question

```
  const [displayFirstColorPicker, setDisplayFirstColorPicker] = useState(false)
  const [displaySecondColorPicker, setDisplaySecondColorPicker] = useState(false)
```

Am I missing a bracket or something?

Comment: You are trying to pass two objects the the style prop, but it can take only one.

Comment: So how can I make it take two? Is there a way?

Comment: There must be a way to pass two styles into an inline style using a Ternary operator

Comment: try to check this line     displaySecondColorPicker ? showColorPicker : hideColorPicker

Comment: That's not valid javascript. You can't `{}, {}` could easily throw an error, as could the fact you're still using a ternary to use an object as an objects short hand key name. The failure to compile is likely this attempt to declare an object with short hand (i.e. one value syntax like `{ variable }` dynamically via a ternary. I can't imagine that syntactic sugar is supported dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

You are attempting to pass two objects to the style prop.

## Solution

Spread them into a single object.

```
style={{
  ...displaySecondColorPicker ? showColorPicker : hideColorPicker,
  ...activeColorPicker === 'second' ? hideColorPicker : showColorPicker
}}
```

```js
const showColorPicker = {
  display: "block",
}

const hideColorPicker = {
  display: "none",
}

const displaySecondColorPicker = true;
const activeColorPicker = 'second';

const style={
  ...displaySecondColorPicker ? showColorPicker : hideColorPicker,
  ...activeColorPicker === 'second' ? hideColorPicker : showColorPicker
}

console.log({ style });
```

***Warning, order matters so order them in the order you want them to be able to override previously spread keys.***